# Is pp-wave spacetime strongly causal?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, causality

Is [pp-wave](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pp-wave_spacetime) spacetime, strongly casual?

If not, where is it on the [causal ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality_conditions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pp-waves form rather large class of spacetimes since they are parametrized by an arbitrary (if we do not require the spacetime to be vacuum) function $H(u, x) $, and also by the manifold $M_x$ of $x$ coordinates which can be arbitrary Riemannian manifold. Depending on the properties of $H$ and the choice of $M_x$, the causal properties of spacetime can be quite different, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0211086) for details:

- If $-H$ grows *superquadratically* with distance $|x|$ then the spacetime may be *non-distinguishing* (but causal). Recall, that causal spacetime would be non-distinguishing if there are distinct points that have the same past and/or future sets. An example of non-distinguishing causal structure is a Galilean universe: different spatial points at the same moment of time have precisely the same past and future causal sets. And so non-distinguishing pp-wave spacetimes found use in Galilean holography.
- If $-H$ behaves *subquadratically* and $M_x$ is complete, such spacetime would be *globally hyperbolic*.
- If $-H$ grows *at most quadraticaly* spacetime would be *strongly causal*.